# How do I make a discord command that states the date within a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I make a discord command that states the date within a message?  I’m using python and trying to make a command that will respond with “Today’s date is <weekday, month day, year>“  How should I do that?

Edit: The message needs to show up in the server, it’s only showing up in the code using the previous solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `datetime` package that comes with python. You can get the current date and time by using:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
print("Today's date:", today)
```

You'd then send that back to the user using the context parameter from the function.

Reference: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-datetime